# bash file gives error "syntax error near unexpected token `fi'"

Tags: bash

When trying to execute my script below, I get this error:

```
syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
```

file:Ccamcheck.sh is in usr/script

My script:

```
#!/bin/sh
if ps x |grep -v grep |grep -c CCcam >/dev/null
then
echo "cccam... ok"
echo && date >> /var/log/CCcam.ok
else
echo "cccam... restarting"
echo && date >> /var/log/CCcam.check
CCcam
fi
```

Does anyone know why I am receiving this error?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please mention 3 simple things in your post. 1- Sample of input, 2- sample of output, 3- your efforts in code tags and let us know then, as we all are here to learn.

Comment: The code looks correct. Is the syntax error coming from your CCcam script?

Comment: when trying to execute -for testing-on telnet  root#/usr/script/Ccamcheck.sh

Comment: Are there any non-printing characters in the file that might confuse the shell? Try printing it with `LC_ALL=C cat -vt Ccamcheck.sh` and see if anything weird shows up.

Comment: If you just need to know if something is still running, you can use `pkill -0 CCcam`.

Comment: You can check for shell syntax errors with `shellcheck` - there's an online version available as well as a package you can install to run locally.

Comment: @ddinc - I don't think that `ps x |pgrep -v pgrep |pgrep -c cccam_2.3.2` does what you want.

Comment: .... same for `echo && date >> /var/log/CCcam.ok`

Comment: have you followed up on @dlink's advice suggesting that the error comes from `CCcam` itself?

Comment: I have managed to get no errors but script is not executing !

Comment: opened another thread as the subject changed:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54288950/executing-a-shell-script-fails